# Error while deploying thee cube in SSDT SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2012-express

I have created a simple cube through SSDT of SQL Server 2012.

While trying to deploy the cube below exception is thrown:

> Error  11
>   The project could not be deployed to the 'ARW-MUM-WK-1022' server because of the following connectivity problems :  A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.
>   To verify or update the name of the target server, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server.      0   0

The test connection of the data source was successful.

Project Property is shown below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the server field try ComputerName\MsSQLInstanceName

Comment: but is is asked for server not for DB instance.

Comment: even its not working!!

Comment: Does the account that you are using to Deploy the cube, have permissions to do that on the instance in question ?